# How to explore relationship between two set of LCA

Tags: latent-class

I’ve performed 2 different LCA in r with poLCA package.

1st  LCA to identify subgroups of children in my sample. Results showed 4 profiles.

2sd  LCA to identify subgroup of parents. Results showed 2 profiles.

Now I’d like to explore the relationship between profiles from 1st and second LCA. I’m new with LCA and I just can’t find information/code  on how to test the relationship with to set of LCA.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is LCA a [latent class model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_class_model) or something else?

Comment: Yes latent class model